# "What links here" for Beans

Tags: views, entities, blocks

I'm using an Entity Reference field (unlimited entries) and a View to include desired Beans on node pages. How can I create a view similar to node/%/backlinks which allows me to see all the nodes that reference a particular block?

So far, I have a View of Content. It includes a relationship to the Referenced Entity (Block) and a Contextual Filter on Block ID. I want to include this View as a menu item on the Block itself, but blocks aren't displayed with their BID, they use a transliterated version of the label as an alias.

I need to find a way to access the Block ID from the alias, or somehow expose a transliterated version of the Label through Views.

Comment: What do you mean by beans?

Comment: Block content https://www.drupal.org/project/bean

Comment: Please use edit link under your question, and provide links directly in question.

Comment: Why? I'm replying to your comment. If a user doesn't know what beans are, they probably can't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is that you are focusing on the label. You need to use a contextual filter of **'Block: Block Delta'**. Then you can add a menu tab to views using this path:

```
block/%/back-links
```

Comment: That's exactly the answer that I was looking for. I had everything set up with the menu tab and view path, just couldn't figure out what to use for the contextual filter.